# Jquery .when() and .then() not working?

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I had try something with the below:

```
$.when($(smtg).fadeOut(300)).then($(smtg).fadeIn(300));
```

What's wrong with it while the document at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/
Chrome console says Uncaught type error: has no method when

@@''

Comment: Then I suppose `fadeOut()` isn't `Deferred-compatible`?

Answer (score 4):

Edit: You need jQuery 1.5+

OR simply do this:

```
$(smtg).fadeOut(300, function() {
    $(smtg).fadeIn(300);
});
```

This basically runs the fadeOut first, once the animation is done then it will run the callback function in our case the fadeIn

Comment: I tried this, the looks is somehow weird. The 1st hasn't yet fadeout and the 2nd ady came in.

Comment: why are trying to fadeOut the same thing then fade it in immediately after?

Comment: just to have some interactive field seems it was a dynamic form with dragdrop.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest possibility, you are using an older (than 1.5) version of jQuery.